# how to replace bp-default folder in buddypress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I have copied bp-default folder and did some changes in new folder, I want buddypress to use my new bp-default folder, copied and named 'custom-bp-default'. How can I do that ?

Comment: I need to use multiple themes, so can't make changes in bp-default itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get BuddyPress to recognize your new theme do the following.

Rename

1. In your 'custom-bp-default' folder edit style.css and change the name of your theme to something different e.g. Theme Name: My Custom Theme, (this is located at the top of the theme in the /*Comments*/)
2. Go to your WordPress Backend and activate your new theme.
3. Done!